# How to delete rows in SQLite database where rows older than 30 days using c# ？

Tags: c#, sqlite

There is  a SQLite data table  with a `lastVisited` column which is *REAL* type .

I hope to delete rows using C# where `lastVisited` column are older than 30 days (This is a  parameter, maybe it's 45, 60, or other), how can I do?

Comment: It's unusual to have real data type to store a timestamp. how the datetime is encoded and then inserted in this column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REAL is one the supported data type for storing dates :

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
> and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
> are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
> values:
>
> - TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November
>   24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> - INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Julian days would be in the 2400000..2500000 range, and you can delete old values with something like :

```
DELETE ...
WHERE lastVisited < julianday('now') - 30
```